# Firebase storage getDownloadURL as src for audio element gives in Safari only an "Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotSupportedError:"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, safari, firebase-storage, html5-audio

I'm using Firebase database and storage to play mp3 files in my vue js web application.

I have a playlist of `songRecords` which contain a field called `songFileUrl` where I have stored the `getDownloadURL`.

onClick I set the `song.songFileUrl` as source for the audio element

```js
audioElement.src = song.songFileUrl
audioElement.play();
```

This all works perfectly fine for all songs in Chrome but not at all in Safari.
Safari gives me the following...

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported.`

Safari will play audio files if I use a url like this

`https://example.com/path/to-public/song/song.mp3`

But a firebase downloadUrl like this gives the NotSupportedError

`"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/site-sttw.appspot.com/o/songFiles%egFileRef?alt=media&token=eg4444-4444-4444"`

So, it seems to me that Safari doesnt recognise the firebase url as a valid source.

Havent been able to find a solution to why that is happening or what I need to supply Safari as an audioElement source url. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seemed the error was not the url but the way I was using the audio tag.

In Chrome you can use the audio tag and change the src attribute on the audio tag. Once src is updated you can call .play()

```html
<audio controls src="songUrlRef"></audio>
```

However, to get things to work in Safari as well I needed to use the source tag like this.

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="songUrlRef" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Additionally, when using the source tag I had to call .load() before .play() to get the new source to play.